# Distribute given number in a greedy manner

Tags: java, arrays, math, distribution, greedy

I am hitting a wall in coming up with an equation to this simple question.  I need a different perspective coming up with an algorithm.  I have a number `x` and I want to distribute it to `n` elements in a greedy manner.

```
For x=9, n=3
[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9] OR [3,3,3]
```

```
For x=10, n=3
[1,2,3,4],[5,6,7],[8,9,10] OR [4,3,3]
```

```
For x=11, n=3
[1,2,3,4],[5,6,7,8],[9,10,11] OR [4,4,3]
```

```
For x=12, n=3
[1,2,3,4],[5,6,7,8],[9,10,11,12] OR [4,4,4]
```

Comment: I don't quite get what you're trying to achieve. Distributing numbers 1 to x into n arrays or splitting x into n integer components doesn't seem to hard.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I understand, you need to get  array like `[4,4,3]`. So use integer division and modulo operation

```
smallvalue = x / n ;  //integer division
largecount = x % n;   //number of larger values
smallcount = n - largecount
```

Now fill array with `largecount` quantity of `smallvalue+1` and then with `smallcount` of `smallvalue`

If you need result `[1,2,3,4],[5,6,7,8],[9,10,11]` - use the same information to generate it.